# How to input a line longer than 4095 characters in Java?

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

I have no idea why the length of l String is no more than 4095 no matter how long the line I give as input is. I really have no idea where is the mistake. I think it is a terminal rule or something, but how can I bypass that in Java? As you can see I use a BufferedReader and it's readLine() method and I need to read lines of huge proportions. Ran out of options already.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Krazki {
    public static int solve() {
        try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String l = br.readLine();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(l.split("\\s")[0]);
        int m =  Integer.parseInt(l.split("\\s")[1]);
        if(n < m) {
            return 0;
        }
        int[] width = new int[n + 2];
        width[0] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        l = br.readLine();
        String[] line = l.split("\\s", n);
        for(int i = 1; i <= n;i++){
            width[i] = Math.min(width[i-1], Integer.parseInt(line[i-1]));
        }
        width[n + 1] = 0;
        int res = n + 1;
        line = br.readLine().split("\\s");
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
            if(res > 0) {
                res--;
            }
            while(width[res] < Integer.parseInt(line[i])) {
                res--;
            }
        }
        br.close();
        return res;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solve());
    }
}
```

Comment: *I need to read lines of huge proportions.* Why are you trying to read from System.in()? Why would you expect a user to type "huge portions'? Would the data not be contained in a file?

Comment: Huge proportion means up to 2400000 characters. Strangely enough the data is contained in a file, but the obligatory requirements state that the data has to be copied into terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (virtually<sup>1</sup>) no limit on the length of a line that you can input in Java.

If you are seeing a line length limit of 4096 characters, it is *probably* imposed by the command shell or console application that you are using to enter the data.  That is not a problem that can be solved directly in a Java application.

The line length limit is typically OS specific, and needs to be addresses by OS specific means.

However, a more practical approach would to change your application to:

- take input from a file, where there should not be any line length limits, or
- implement an line continuation syntax that allows the user to input overly long lines as multiple lines.

---

<sup>1 - An application probably cannot cope with a line longer than ~2<sup>31</sup> characters, because `String` and `StringBuffer` use arrays and arrays are limited to that many elements.  In addition, an application would typically need enough memory to hold the complete line.</sup>